# Is there a way to change the outline border color of the OTP fields using PinCodeTextField plugin

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm new to Flutter. I'm using PinCodeTextField https://pub.dev/packages/pin_code_fields plugin to create OTP Text field I want the text field to be in different color but I couldn't find the decoration property to change the colour.

Answer (score 2):

Spent hours looking for the same problem and finaly found a way around.

1. Searck for a file ‘otp_field_style.dart’ through find.
2. Open the file and you will see following:

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

```
import 'package:<myApp’s Constants>/constants/constants.dart';

class OtpFieldStyle {
      /// The background color for outlined box.
    
      final Color backgroundColor;
    
      /// The border color text field.
    
      final Color borderColor;
    
      /// The border color of text field when in focus.
    
      final Color focusBorderColor;
    
      /// The border color of text field when disabled.
    
      final Color disabledBorderColor;
    
      /// The border color of text field when in focus.
    
      final Color enabledBorderColor;
    
      /// The border color of text field when disabled.
    
      final Color errorBorderColor;
    
      OtpFieldStyle(
          {this.backgroundColor: kFillShade7,
          this.borderColor: kOrange4,
          this.focusBorderColor: kOrange1,
          this.disabledBorderColor: kFillShade4,
          this.enabledBorderColor: kFillShade2,
          this.errorBorderColor: Colors.red});
    }
```

3. Now, you can change the colors by giving the hard values,
   OR
4. Import your constants.dart file (where one normally defines the constants, including colors etc)  in this and link the colors through it e.g,

   import 'package:/constants/constants.dart';

is my contants file, I have linked my kColors in above code,

just change it to appropriate link for your constants dart file.
5.  Save and close  ‘otp_field_style.dart’.
You can change the colors through your defined constants, I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

you can use this properties to change the colors

```
pinTheme: PinTheme(
          shape: PinCodeFieldShape.box,
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(5),
          fieldHeight: 50,
          fieldWidth: 40,
          activeFillColor: Colors.black,
         inactiveColor: Colors.deepOrange,
         
            inactiveFillColor: Colors.green,
            selectedFillColor: Colors.deepPurple,
            selectedColor: Colors.greenAccent,
            activeColor: Colors.blue
            

        ),
```

Comment: @robert-stag did this help you ?

Answer (score 0):

```
PinTheme(
      activeFillColor: Colors.white,
      selectedFillColor: Colors.white,
      inactiveFillColor: Colors.white,
      inactiveColor: borderColor,
      activeColor: borderColor,
      selectedColor: borderColor
    }
```

Using pin theme like this.